# Cannot access AWS MySQL instance from any computer other than my own (including Cloud9)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I spun up a mysql RDS instance in AWS the other day and am able to connect to it from my computer via powershell.  However, when i am on another computer, including a virtual terminal in the cloud9 IDE, I cannot get into the mysql database. I am VERY new to AWS, so i don't know where to go next.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to whitelist the IP of your RDS instance? Looks like some firewall prevents your outbound connections, or your security group does not include the ranges you need to whitelist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote that you're able to connect from your own computer but you can't when you're on another computer, so it's probably the inbound rules on the security group you have on that RDS, by default when you're creating a free-tier RDS, your ip address is captured and stored in the security group.

So what you need to do is to navigate to that RDS instance, click on the security group attached to it, modify the inbound rules and either make it publicly available `0.0.0.0/0` which is unsecrue and unrecommended but works if you're just exploring AWS, or you'd add in the ip address of the computer you're trying to access it from.

Comment: That was it.  I was trying to do that for the Cloud9 instance following these instructions (https://community.c9.io/t/connecting-to-amazon-rds/11338/2) but adding the CIDR after running the command in step 3 wasn't working.  So I thought I was doing something wrong, but it turns out the IP address it was returning was wrong.  I added the one in the Cloud9 terminal tab header and it worked like a charm.  Thanks!